# Python set up on mac

Tags: osx, python

My /usr/bin contains the following installs of python

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov 18 06:17 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov 18 06:17 pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Nov 18 06:17 pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  62752 Nov 18 06:17 pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov 18 06:17 python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov 18 06:17 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov 18 06:17 python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov 18 06:17 python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Nov 18 06:17 python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Nov 18 06:17 python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5
-rwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel    925 Nov 18 06:17 python-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  62752 Nov 18 06:17 python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     63 Mar  6 13:23 python3.2 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin/python3.2
```

I would have thought that python would be a link to any of the versions installed, but it is not. It appears to be a python executable

```
15:00:33 /usr/bin $ python -V
Python 2.7.1
```

Another install shows the same version

```
15:01:36 /usr/bin $ pythonw2.7 -V
Python 2.7.1
```

Checksums are, however not the same

```
15:02:15 /usr/bin $ sum python2.7
60959 35 python2.7

15:03:18 /usr/bin $ sum python
10360 62 python
```

**I wonder .. is it ok to actually**

```
rm python
ln -s python3.2 python
```

System: MAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not rename instead of remove:

```
mv python python.original
```